# Firefox mimetypes.rdf

Tags: linux, firefox

Is it possible to create a default `mimeTypes.rdf`  file for all the existing and new users ? 
So that whenever a user opens the firefox for the very first time, he will get the specified rdf file in his profile @ `~/.mozilla/firefox/*/mimeTypes.rdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are creating users with `useradd` you can file directory `/etc/skel` to put files and directories in users home directories.

> `man useradd`: The skeleton directory, which contains files and directories to be
>   copied in the users home directory, when the home directory is created
>   by useradd.

So you should create two files:

- `/etc/skel/.mozilla/firefox/PROFILE_NAME/mimeTypes.rdf` with content that you need
- `/etc/skel/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` with:

  ```
  [General]
  StartWithLastProfile=1

  [Profile0]
  Name=Default User
  IsRelative=1
  Path=PROFILE_NAME
  Default=1
  ```

It should do the work with new users.

Answer (score 0):

I found occurrences of `/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/profile/mimeTypes.rdf` on the web, but I'm not sure it will be used by recent versions of firefox. Might be worth a try!